# Autoselect option, and autocomplete textarea values onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose there is a link (two links, actually), each supposed to be doing something similar and each doing something different.

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" name="A">#</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" name="A">Product A</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" name="B">#</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" name="B">Product B</a>
etc.
```

When the # anchor is clicked, it needs to open a popup, prompt for a number, then on submit, autoselect the option and set textarea value to the number entered.

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>             
    <option value="A">Spies</option>                            
    <option value="B">Militia</option>      
</select>   
</td>
<td><input value="0" type="text"></td>
```

But when the Product anchor is clicked, it needs to do the same thing, but just set the selected element to the corresponding value (Product A autoselects the selects to A, etc.)

I have some stuff in JavaScript to make this work, but I'd like it to be in jQuery, and am having a hard time figuring it out.

Some JS:
The anchors have `onclick="var newNumUnits=prompt('How many of Product X do you want to default to? 'Enter amount here'); quickFill(1111115,newNumUnits);"`, which takes care of a lot of the stuff, but it gets "large" and "complicated", and I'd really like to see the code be rendered easier (if possible) in jQuery.

```
function quickFill(ProdID, num) {
    for(i=0; i<document.myForm.elements.length; i++) {
        fieldname = document.myForm.elements[i].name;
        fieldvalue = document.myForm.elements[i].value;
        if (fieldname.indexOf("_") != -1) {
            fieldNameArray = fieldname.split("_");
            smallFieldName = fieldNameArray[0];
            myPUID = fieldNameArray[1];
            if (smallFieldName == "ProdID") {
                selectfield = document.myForm.elements[i];
                for (var j=0; j<selectfield.options.length;j++) {
                    if (selectfield.options[j].value == ProdID) {
                        selectfield.options[j].selected=true;
                        textinputfield = document.getElementById("num_"+myPUID);
                        textinputfield.value=num;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    updateStatus();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The actual, unedited code that I'm currently working with:

```
<tr class="L1">
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="map.php?x=1898&y=2018">1898, 2018</a>
    </td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><a href="structDetail.php?x=1898&y=2018">Combat Outpost</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="struct[213][str]">
            <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
            <option value="U2" data-price="4000">Blackshirts</option>
            <option value="U3" data-price="6000">Spies</option>
            <option value="U4" data-price="8000">Partisans</option>
            <option value="U7" data-price="15000">Rebels</option>
            <option value="U11" data-price="80000">Oerlikon Cannons</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt" name="struct[213][numUnits]" value="0" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="L2">
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="map.php?x=1900&y=2018">1900, 2018</a>
    </td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><a href="structDetail.php?x=1900&y=2018">Combat Outpost</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="struct[329][str]">
            <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
            <option value="U2" data-price="4000">Blackshirts</option>
            <option value="U3" data-price="6000">Spies</option>
            <option value="U4" data-price="8000">Partisans</option>
            <option value="U7" data-price="15000">Rebels</option>
            <option value="U11" data-price="80000">Oerlikon Cannons</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt" name="struct[329][numUnits]" value="0" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="L2">
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="map.php?x=1901&y=2018">1901, 2018</a>
    </td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><a href="structDetail.php?x=1901&y=2018">Military Installation</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="struct[330][str]">
            <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
            <option value="U1" data-price="1200">K-9 Corps</option>
            <option value="U5" data-price="9000">Riflemen</option>
            <option value="U6" data-price="11000">Sappers</option>
            <option value="U8" data-price="24000">J&#228;gers</option>
            <option value="U9" data-price="27000">Commandos</option>
            <option value="U10" data-price="33000">Red Berets</option>
            <option value="U12" data-price="110000">Ford GPW</option>
            <option value="U13" data-price="222000">M3 Half-tracks</option>
            <option value="U14" data-price="350000">7TP</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt" name="struct[330][numUnits]" value="0" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="L2">
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="map.php?x=1901&y=2017">1901, 2017</a>
    </td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><a href="structDetail.php?x=1901&y=2017">Light Airfield</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="struct[331][str]">
            <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
            <option value="U15" data-price="155000">PZL.23 Kara&#347;</option>
            <option value="U16" data-price="175000">R-4 Hoverfly</option>
            <option value="U17" data-price="650000">PZL P.11</option>
            <option value="U18" data-price="1050000">P-39 Airacobra</option>
            <option value="U19" data-price="1500000">C-46 Commando</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt" name="struct[331][numUnits]" value="0" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Some stuff that I experimented with before, in JavaScript, that works (goes with the the quickFill function posted above:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="var newNumUnits=prompt('How many units do you want to default to? \nClick the unit name instead of the number sign to skip this step.','Enter amount here'); quickFill(U3,newNumUnits);">#</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="quickFill(U3);">Spies</a>
<br>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="var newNumUnits=prompt('How many units do you want to default to? \nClick the unit name instead of the number sign to skip this step.','Enter amount here'); quickFill(U2,newNumUnits);">#</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="quickFill(U2);">Blackshirts</a>
```

That style of anchors then continues for about 30 more combos, different U#'s, different names. What needs to happen is that when the anchor with text is clicked, all selects that contain that same U# are then auto-selected to it, and when the # anchor is clicked, the same thing happens, but also changes the corresponding textarea to the number entered in the  prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do some changes to the HTML `<a>` tags first:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" name="A" data-type="hash">#</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" name="A" data-type="product">Product A</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" name="B" data-type="hash">#</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" name="B" data-type="product">Product B</a>

<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>               
    <option value="A">Spies</option>                          
    <option value="B">Militia</option>        
</select>   
<input value="0" type="text">
```

Now in jQuery you will need to listen for the click event of the `<a>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var a_name = $(this).attr('name');

        if ($(this).data('type') === 'hash') {
            var answer = prompt('Type your selection', '');

            $('select option').prop('selected', false);
            $('select option[value="' + a_name + '"]').prop('selected', true);
            $('input').val(answer);
        } else if ($(this).data('type') === 'product') {
            $('select option').prop('selected', false);
            $('select option[value="' + a_name + '"]').prop('selected', true);
        }
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KArt8/1/)**

### Update since you showed me full code =)

**HTML**

```
<table id="someID">
    <tr class="L1">
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="map.php?x=1898&y=2018">1898, 2018</a>

        </td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td><a href="structDetail.php?x=1898&y=2018">Combat Outpost</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="struct[213][str]">
                <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
                <option value="U2" data-price="4000">Blackshirts</option>
                <option value="U3" data-price="6000">Spies</option>
                <option value="U4" data-price="8000">Partisans</option>
                <option value="U7" data-price="15000">Rebels</option>
                <option value="U11" data-price="80000">Oerlikon Cannons</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt" name="struct[213][numUnits]" value="0" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="L2">
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="map.php?x=1900&y=2018">1900, 2018</a>

        </td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td><a href="structDetail.php?x=1900&y=2018">Combat Outpost</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="struct[329][str]">
                <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
                <option value="U2" data-price="4000">Blackshirts</option>
                <option value="U3" data-price="6000">Spies</option>
                <option value="U4" data-price="8000">Partisans</option>
                <option value="U7" data-price="15000">Rebels</option>
                <option value="U11" data-price="80000">Oerlikon Cannons</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt" name="struct[329][numUnits]" value="0" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="L2">
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="map.php?x=1901&y=2018">1901, 2018</a>

        </td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td><a href="structDetail.php?x=1901&y=2018">Military Installation</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="struct[330][str]">
                <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
                <option value="U1" data-price="1200">K-9 Corps</option>
                <option value="U5" data-price="9000">Riflemen</option>
                <option value="U6" data-price="11000">Sappers</option>
                <option value="U8" data-price="24000">J&#228;gers</option>
                <option value="U9" data-price="27000">Commandos</option>
                <option value="U10" data-price="33000">Red Berets</option>
                <option value="U12" data-price="110000">Ford GPW</option>
                <option value="U13" data-price="222000">M3 Half-tracks</option>
                <option value="U14" data-price="350000">7TP</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt" name="struct[330][numUnits]" value="0" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="L2">
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="map.php?x=1901&y=2017">1901, 2017</a>

        </td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td><a href="structDetail.php?x=1901&y=2017">Light Airfield</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="struct[331][str]">
                <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
                <option value="U15" data-price="155000">PZL.23 Kara&#347;</option>
                <option value="U16" data-price="175000">R-4 Hoverfly</option>
                <option value="U17" data-price="650000">PZL P.11</option>
                <option value="U18" data-price="1050000">P-39 Airacobra</option>
                <option value="U19" data-price="1500000">C-46 Commando</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt" name="struct[331][numUnits]" value="0" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<div id="quickChoice"> <a style="cursor:pointer;">#</a>

<a style="cursor:pointer;">Spies</a>

    <br>
<a style="cursor:pointer;">#</a>

<a style="cursor:pointer;">Blackshirts</a>

    <br>
<a style="cursor:pointer;">#</a>

<a style="cursor:pointer;">Riflemen</a>

    <br>
<a style="cursor:pointer;">#</a>

<a style="cursor:pointer;">Sappers</a>

    <br>
<a style="cursor:pointer;">#</a>

<a style="cursor:pointer;">R-4 Hoverfly</a>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#quickChoice').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        // dont allow the <a> to perform its default functionality
        e.preventDefault();

        // get content of <a> tag
        var contents = $(this).text();

        // user clicked hash symbol
        if (contents === '#') {

            // get the contents of next available <a> tag
            var select_choice = $(this).next('a').text();

            // promp for number
            var answer = prompt('Type your selection', '');

            // go through table
            // find any <selects> that have <options>
            // filter options based on <a> contents next to hash
            // make it selected
            // for each matching <option> go to parent <td> and find the next <td> because we need to populate the <input> tag
            // populate the <input>
            $('table#someID')
                .find('select')
                .find('option')
                .filter(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() === select_choice) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }).prop('selected', true)
                    .each(function () {
                        $(this)
                            .parents('td')
                            .first()
                            .next('td')
                            .find('input[type="text"]')
                            .val(answer);
                    });

        } else {

            // user did not click hash but rather the text value
            var select_choice = $(this).text();

            // same as above but we don't have to populate the <input> at all
            $('table')
                .find('select')
                .find('option')
                .filter(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() === select_choice) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }).prop('selected', true);
        }
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KArt8/4/)**

Comment: That works, somewhat. Problems are that it fails to work with multiple select/text area combos. I had something written in the question that appears to have been edited away, that those select/text area combos are multiple, some are identical (Values A and B, but a number of them), others are different (Values C and D; values E, F, and G; etc.) I've tried fiddling with your answer to get it to work with what I need, but I cannot seem to figure that part out. Adding "[value="' + a_name + '"]" to the prop('selected', false) and $('input').val(answer) statements fails...

Comment: It would be beneficial to see how your HTML actually looks rather than stating `<!--(there's a number of these, in the same fashion, some the same values, others different)-->`. If I was psychic you can bet I wouldn't be a programmer =) let me know when you've made an update and feel free to update the JSfiddle I provided as well

Comment: I've updated the code, full copy/paste this time; instead of trying to simplify stuff. The select names and textarea names need to remain the same (if possible), to work with other stuff. If there's anything else you need, please let me know. I'm at a loss with trying to fiddle with your code...plus, it seems to have disabled dropdown menu links on the page the code's added to (but, I'm not sure if that's your code doing that or one of my attempted edits)

Comment: I am extremely confused so let's focus on `<tr class="L1">`. How is the clicking of either of those `<a>` tags supposed to correlate to selecting an `<option>` from `<select name="struct[213][str]">`? How is the clicking of `<a href="structDetail.php?x=1898&y=2018">Combat Outpost</a>` supposed to change the `<select>` field to match it if there is no `<option>Combat Outpost</option>` available? I really hope you can explain this otherwise what you are doing is not going to be easily automated with jQuery.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's being asked, but let me try to explain it a little better. In the code, there are two Combat Outposts. What I'm liking simplified by jQuery, is that when the text `<a>` tag for either spies or blackshirts (since they are uniform in the code as being under outposts) are clicked, the select elements that contain spies/blackshirts are selected for spies/blackshirts; and when the # `<a>` is clicked, it does the same but also adds the inputted number  in the corresponding textarea. This would be nice to be able to expand to other `<a>`'s, with Riflemen, Sappers, etc.

Comment: If needed, as stated, I have tinkered around with javascript and have something in javascript that works, but I'd like it in simpler jQuery (as well, to hopefully teach me a thing about jQuery as well)...I could probably get that correlated to a jsFiddle or put it online for you to see how it used-to/currently functions. Haven't used jsFiddle much, so it could take a little time.

Comment: I think I get it now. I was under the impression that the `<tr class="L1">` contains the Hash and Product `<a>` tags but I now see that those links are not even inside the `<tr>`'s at all. I'll update my post when I can

Comment: Sorry, I was out of town today. Yes, that works 100%. Plus, I like the comments explaining things (I'll now have to review the code in detail to learn more). Much thanks.